# Importing 'prefixed-line' csv into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv formatted like below which I'd like to import into pandas. Basically, it is a bunch of measurements and data from multiple samples.

```
dataformat1,sample1,sample_source,start_time
dataformat2,parameter1,spec_a_1,spec_b_1,measurement1
dataformat2,parameter2,spec_a_2,spec_b_2,measurement2
dataformat2,parameter3,spec_a_3,spec_b_3,measurement3
dataformat3,result_code_for_sample1,completion_time_for_sample1
...
dataformat1,sampleN,sample_source,start_time
dataformat2,parameter1,spec_a_1,spec_b_1,measurement1
dataformat2,parameter2,spec_a_2,spec_b_2,measurement2
dataformat2,parameter3,spec_a_3,spec_b_3,measurement3
dataformat3,result_code_for_sampleN,completion_time_for_sampleN
```

Essentially, the first field of the csv is describing the data format of the rest of that line. In the pandas dataframe I would like to import all these into a single dataframe and fill them to relevant section. I am currently planning to do this by:

1. prepending the line number into the csv
2. reading each `dataformat#` into a separate dataframe
3. combining, sorting, and ffill/bfill/unpivot(?) shenanigans to fill in all the data

I assume this will work, but I am wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this either within pandas or using some other library. It is a somewhat common data logging paradigm in the work I do.

Comment: Please define "relevant section".  Please provide one example of each and every different dateformats

Comment: if you need every `dataformat#` in separated dataframe then maybe `.groupby(first_column)`

Comment: @RaymondKwok "data" format not "date" format. Each of the columns have different meanings depending on the value of the first column in the csv, which I'm calling "dataformat" above.

Comment: @RaymondKwok For 'Relevant Section', basically, I'm wanting to add in the column values associated to each 'Sample'.
For example, the data collected for a batch of apples...
Sample1 is an individual apple, parameter1 is the weight, parameter2 is the diameter, parameter3 is the height ...
Sample2 is a different apple, with the same parameters measured. These apply to the dataformats preceding/succeeding that, until a different sample is described via dataformat1.

Comment: so you can use `.groupby(first_column).apply(func)` where `func` uses ffill/bfill?